# How to use XIRR from VBA Script

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet that shows deposits to a bank account, plus periodically I check the balance and put that in the spreadsheet.  I'd like to make a macro that calculates the to-date equivalent return (*i.e.*, if I have this sequence of deposits, and then the account balance is $X, then the equivalent rate of interest is Y%).  For example, I might have:

```
 1-Jan-2010  $100
22-Apr-2011  $200
14-Feb-2012        $310
28-Aug-2013  $500
 9-May-2014        $790  # account lost value!
```

I can get the dates and deposits into a function (along with the ending balance) but I can't get XIRR to work right.  I know this is ugly VBA (not a language I know) but here's what I have:

```
Public Function MyXIRR(Dates As Range, Trans As Range, Balance As Double)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Double
    Dim dateArray() As Date
    Dim valArray() As Double

    ReDim dateArray(Dates.Count + 1)
    ReDim valArray(Trans.Count + 1)

    For i = 1 To Dates.Count
        dateArray(i - 1) = Dates.Item(i)
        Next i

    For i = 1 To Trans.Count
        valArray(i - 1) = Trans.Item(i)
        Next i

    dateArray(Dates.Count) = DateAdd("d", 1, Dates.Item(Dates.Count))
    valArray(Trans.Count) = -1 * Balance

    For i = 0 To Dates.Count
        dateArray(i) = Format(dateArray(i), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        Next i

    MsgBox ("Hello")
    x = Application.Xirr(valArray, dateArray, 0.01)
    MsgBox (x)
'    MyXIRR = Dates.Count * 100 + Trans.Count
'    MyXIRR = dateArray(6)
    MyXIRR = valArray(3)
End Function
```

(The comments and MsgBox at the end are my various attempts to figure out what's going on; ideally, I'd just have a formula in a cell: `=MyXIRR( A2:A6, B2:B6, C6 )` which would return the equivalent interest rate.)

I think what's happening is that when I call `Application.Xirr`, I'm getting a `#VALUE` exception (error?)  But I don't know how to debug it, examine the arrays passed to Xirr, or figure out what's wrong.

[image: Screenshot of Spreadsheet]

[image: Screenshot from Debugger]

Comment: Your macro works good on my PC. The output is 0.02639.

Comment: Your macro works OK here, also.  But it did not when I first tried it.  When I used it on a fresh workbook though, everything was OK so I assume something was interfering in the initial workbook I was using.

Comment: Weird, thanks for checking.  I guess I have something else interfering with it.  Maybe I need to start a fresh worksheet.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether this is The Answer, or whether I've merely swept the problem under a different rug, but I was able to get my function to work reliably by converting the `dateArray` to an array of Strings, where each String is a parseable date.

```
Public Function MyXIRR(Dates As Range, Trans As Range, Balance As Double)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Double
    Dim dateArray() As Date
    Dim dateStrings() As String
    Dim valArray() As Double

    ReDim dateArray(Dates.Count)
    ReDim valArray(Trans.Count)
    ReDim dateStrings(Dates.Count)

    For i = 1 To Dates.Count
        dateArray(i - 1) = Dates.Item(i).Value
        Next i

    For i = 1 To Trans.Count
        valArray(i - 1) = Trans.Item(i).Value
        Next i

    dateArray(Dates.Count) = DateAdd("d", 1, Dates.Item(Dates.Count))
    valArray(Trans.Count) = -1 * Balance

    For i = 0 To Dates.Count
        dateStrings(i) = Format(dateArray(i), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Next i

    MyXIRR = Application.WorksheetFunction.Xirr(valArray, dateStrings, 0.01)
End Function
```

Comment: Yes your conversion to `"mm/dd/yyyy"` string format works like a charm. I think Microsoft VBA docs are wrong they state: "_Dates should be entered by using the DATE function, or as results of other formulas or functions. For example, use DATE(2008,5,23) for the 23rd day of May, 2008. **Problems can occur if dates are entered as text**._" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.xirr But apparently the opposite is true!

Answer (score 0):

The macro in the original question didn't work for me either.

However, what did work reliably was to convert the date array into doubles (using the `CDbl` function) and pass that to the XIRR function.